# Get rows results from a JOIN with IF statement

Tags: mysql

I have 'transactions' table:

```
id user amount plan_id
1   1     11      1       
2   1     9       2
3   1     10      2
4   2     10      3
5   1     7       4
6   1     5       4
7   1     6       5
8   3     3       8
7   1     7       5
```

And the 'plans' table:

```
plan_id type status
  1      0     0
  2      1     1
  3      1     0
  4      1     0
  5      0     1
```

I need to get the sum of the amounts for each plan_id given in 'transactions'. However, if the type is '0' and the status is '1' in 'plans' table for an specific plan_id, then ONLY in this case the sum would return '0'.

So this is what would be returned:

```
plan_id earnings
   1      11     
   2      19
   4      12
   5       0  // it should be 13, but because type=0 and status=1, sum returns 0
```

so far I have:

```
SELECT t.plan_id, 
SUM( IF( p.type = 0 and p.status = 1 , 0, t.amount ) ) as earnings
FROM transactions as t
WHERE t.user = 1
INNER JOIN plans as p ON t.plan_id=p.plan_id;
GROUP BY t.plan_id
```

But it is not working for some reason. I am running out of ideas.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: `WHERE` goes *after* `INNER JOIN`. Aren't you getting a syntax error?

Comment: You can use a single `IF`: `IF(plans.type = 0 AND plans.status = 1, 0, transactions.amount)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query has syntax error as you have used WHERE clause in between JOIN.

I have modified your SQL query and found your expected result if I am correct.

```
SELECT t.plan_id, 
       SUM(IF(p.TYPE = 0 
              AND p.status = 1, 0, t.amount)) AS earnings 
FROM   transactions AS t 
       inner join plans AS p 
               ON t.plan_id = p.plan_id 
WHERE  t.USER = 1 
GROUP  BY t.plan_id;
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t.plan_id, sum(t.amount) as total 
FROM plans as p 
inner join transactions as t on (p.plan_id = t.plan_id) 
where t.user = 1 
group by t.plan_id
```

I think you can simply achieve this using above query

Comment: Don't just post code. You should explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: You remove the code that sets `total` to `0` when `plans.type = 0` and `plans.status = 1`.

Comment: What about the IF statements? When p.type=0 and p.status=1 in 'plans' table for an specific plan_id, then ONLY in this case the sum would return '0'. Please help. Thanks